# How to find the name for a full text catalog

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I use SQL Server 2005, I have a database which uses full-text catalog.

I need to delete the full-text catalog but I do not know its name so I would like to know how to find the name for it.

Any idea thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
USE [YourDbName]

select * from sys.fulltext_catalogs
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to query `sys.fulltext_catalogs` like

```
select name,is_default from sys.fulltext_catalogs
```

Default one will have `is_default = 1`

For more info see here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188779.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I fond the solution on this article:

```
select * from sysfulltextcatalogs
```

FOr me work on MS SQL 2000 and 2005

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldatabaseengine/thread/83b66b90-2b67-4c81-8b7e-3fda500fbb57